# xml parsing error : not well-formed<invalid token> in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, sax

Hi I am working on scraping the XML file. For HTML I have used scrapy and for XML I decided to parse it by using `xml.sax`.

Following is an example code *(don't treat it as a real example)* just to view my doubt:

```
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler
import xml.sax

xmlFilePath = 'users/documents/jobstext.xml'

try:
    parser = xml.sax.make_parser( )
    parser.parse(open(xmlFilePath))

except (xml.sax.SAXParseException), e:
        print "*** PARSER error: %s" % e
        print e,"What is the error actually >>>>"
```

Following is **XML code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jobs>
  <reader><![CDATA[Identity Group]]></reader>
  <readerUrl><![CDATA[http://www.example.com]]></readerUrl>

  <job>
    <title><![CDATA[Architect - OT]]></title>
    <category><![CDATA[LTC/SNF]]></category>
    <jobId><![CDATA[139693]]></jobId>
    <specialization><![CDATA[LTC/SNF]]></specialization>
    <positionType><![CDATA[Travel]]></positionType>
    <description><![CDATA[<DIV>OT&nbsp;needed for a SNF in&nbsp;Oregon.&nbsp; Oregon is a dramatic land of many changes. From the rugged Oregon seacoast, the high mountain passes of the country for Travel Allied Professionals and Travel Nurses. Our clients are among the most prestigious healthcare facilities in the country.</DIV>
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
 </description>
<P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal><FONT size=3><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Symbol; COLOR: black; mso-ascii-font-family: 'Times New Roman'">�</SPAN><SPAN style="COLOR: black"><FONT face="Times New Roman"><SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp; </SPAN>Position will manage 24 ED Rooms with 24/7 accountability<o:p></o:p></FONT></SPAN></FONT></P>
<P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal><FONT size=3><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Symbol; COLOR: black; mso-ascii-font-family: 'Times New Roman'">�</SPAN><SPAN style="COLOR: black"><FONT face="Times New Roman"> <SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp;</SPAN>55 FTEs <o:p></o:p></FONT></SPAN></FONT></P>
  </job>
</jobs>
```

**Result:**

```
*** PARSER error: users/documents/jobstext.xml:13:150: not well-formed <invalid token>
users/documents/jobstext.xml:13:150: not well-formed <invalid token> What is the error actually >>>>
```

What is happening when the execution reaches `<p>` tag and index 150 its displaying an error invalid token? I am expecting this becuase of `?` tag as you can see this in the above error  .

So can anyone please let me know how to solve this error of `not well-formed <invalid token>` in xml parsing,

If I explained in a wrong format, I am sorry, but hope I explained the concept well.

**Edited Code:**

```
<P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt"><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">THE MOST COMPETITIVE RATES IN NM .....<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>
<P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt"><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Busy <?xml:namespace prefix = st1 ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" /><st1:place w:st="on"><st1:PlaceName w:st="on">Acute</st1:PlaceName> <st1:PlaceName w:st="on">Care</st1:PlaceName> <st1:PlaceType w:st="on">Hospital</st1:PlaceType></st1:place> needs Occupational Therapists.&nbsp; Experience with </SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Ortho, Neuro, vestibular balance, aquatic a plus!<SPAN style="COLOR: black">&nbsp; New grads welcome.<SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp; </SPAN>Signon Bonus and help with relocation.<SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp; </SPAN>For more details please call or email Carole 800 995 2673 X1329 or <A href="mailto:cs@coremedicalgroup.com"><SPAN style="mso-bidi-font-weight: bold; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt">cs@coremedicalgroup.com</SPAN></A><o:p></o:p></SPAN></SPAN></P>
```

Comment: @Quentin: The above two tags(for example) executed without error as u indicated wiht class="Msnormal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question has changed...

XML attributes must be quoted.

For example: `class=MsoNormal` should be `class="MsoNormal"`

Comment: Actually the theme is my xml file has many job related data, so here i pasted only the xml related to one job. The same is executed for some other <p> tags with no commas as i edited in the above .

Comment: ok i have pasted only paragraph tags now directly copying from code without editing can u tell me whats wrong now

Comment: @shivakrishna — If you reduce the XML to `<xml><P class=MsoNormal></p></xml>` then it still gives that error. **attribute values must be quoted**. You might have other errors, but that one is the first.

Comment: oh k thanks Quentin, can we remove that '?' from p tag during execution(I want to execute without that hope that work without errors because there are no other errors more than in p tag])

Answer (score 1):

Your `description` has no end tag and the CDATA section inside it is never terminated … although I'd expect it to error at the end of the document rather than on the third line of data for that element.

Comment: Thanks for u r reply yes actually i updated end tag for description. But really in my xml there is no end tag for cdata. But the error is at <p> tag please can u tell me whats wrong in p tag    and how to avoid error\

Comment: @shivakrishna — The CDATA section still isn't be terminated.

Comment: Dont mind actually there is no end tag for any cdata in my xml but everything is working. Please focus on the para tag because everything in xml is working fine but in the para tags i had pasted above at column 150 its showing an error. so how to ignore such kind of errors